# call to undefind function GetEntityManager() when running doctrine commands

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am trying to run doctrine commands on my windows OS. i am using following command,

```
"vendor/bin/doctrine.bat" orm:schema-tool:create
```

Following is my cli-config.php

```
<?php
// cli-config.php
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// Any way to access the EntityManager from  your application
$em = GetMyEntityManager();

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

i am getting this error

```
call to undefind function GetEnttyManager()
```

i am following http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html for refrence

**EDIT** I reset the tags and now it is for ZF2

Comment: GetEnttyManager or GetMyEntityManager?  It's up to you to configure an entity manager and then make it available via GetMyEntityManager.  If you happen to be using Symfony 2 then using the S2 console command will make life easier.

Comment: Please exactly tag your framework in question. Is it Symfony 2 or ZF2?

Comment: The link you provide does say "You have to adjust this snippet for your specific application or framework and use their facilities to access the Doctrine EntityManager and Connection Resources."

Comment: @AlexP:yes it was meant for Zend Frame work 2 but ZF2 dont have boot strap as its mentioned there

Comment: Can you show is you bootstrap code?

Answer (score 0):

Call doctrine update like this:

```
$ path/to/your/php your/zf2/public/index.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

Note: don't use standard doctrine documentation for zf2 project, there are tutorials and documentations special for doctrine for zf2. Doctrine behaviour in zf2 is not quite the same as in Symfony.